# android "cannot resolve method" error using application object

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I have `MainActitity` where in `onCreate`:

```
BLEApplication mApp = (BLEApplication) BLEApplication.mAppContext();
        mApp.MainActivity = this;
```

Also in `MainActitity`

```
public void EnableDisableButtons(){
            findViewById(R.id.buttonNewGame).setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Class:

```
public class BLEApplication extends Application {
static Activity MainActivity;
```

...
}

```
public class BLE {
...

BLEApplication mApp = (BLEApplication) BLEApplication.mAppContext();        
mApp.MainActivity.EnableDisableButtons();
        mApp.MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.buttonContinueGame).setEnabled(true);
```

I can use `MainActivity.findViewById` to enable activity buttons from class `BLE` but for `EnableDisableButtons()` Studio says "cannot resolve method". I can copy all code from `EnableDisableButtons` to `BLE`, but using method in `MainActivity` seams to me more elegant solution. Why it gives error?

Comment: EnableDisableButtons is not static method you can't access it with class name

Comment: What are you event trying to do? Please read some android tutorials and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I Am not able  to fully understand your code. But as per java concept you need to typecast Activity to your activity like this:

```
public class BLE {
...

BLEApplication mApp = (BLEApplication) BLEApplication.mAppContext();        
((MainActivity)(mApp.MainActivity)).EnableDisableButtons();
        mApp.MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.buttonContinueGame).setEnabled(true);
```

Since your mApp.MainActivity is object of Activity so you need to typecast it to tell which Activity it is , so that it can find the method that you have declared in your activity.

Also mApp.MainActivity gives you object of Activity class in which there is no EnableDisableButtons() method hence this error is there.
Now if you typecast it to MainActivity it will find the method and this error will not come.

Comment: It helps! Also instead `static MainActivity MainActivity;` in `BLEApplication`. Thanks a lot! Non fully understand why `findviewbyid` works for more broad `Activity` object.

Comment: I understood now - R.id.buttonContinueGame is unique, where as written by Damanpreet Singh - Activity is not.

Comment: No the reason is setcontentView done in onCreate.
findViewbyid is method of Activity.java. When you do setcontentView in MainActivity, as it extends from Activity.java gives call to setContentView of Activity.java and view of that window is set.

Now if you do findViewById that too is method of Activity.java it will find the view set by you in setContentView and will give you the view of that id. 

This is the same reason why you can't have two views of same id in your xml. Whereas you can have same id's of views in two different xml's.